# Onclick select all in another span object

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I select all data inside a desired span from a 'a' tag from another span/div/table object?

```
    <td>
    <span class='servkey'>texttoselect</span>
    <a href='#' title='Select all'>select all</a>
    </td>
```

Thanks!

Comment: please share the related html

Comment: @arun-p-johny <td><span class='servkey'>".$key['serverkey']."</span> <a href='#' title='Copy to clipboard'><i class='icon-file'></i></a></td>

Comment: @user2696392 - Your question is not clear, please elaborate

Comment: @bibhu When I press <a>select all</a> I would like that the button selects all text in .servkey

Comment: Selects it how? Highlights it in the page visually as if you dragged over it with your mouse, or programatically copied the content?

Comment: As an add-on, do you want all elements that have the `servkey` class to be selected or just the one above the link? Seeing as you're using a class, I assume that some other element(s) on the page use the class as well. Not completely sure though because you haven't shown us enough of your code.

Comment: @j08691 Highlights it in the page visually as if you dragged over it with your mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code just selects the contents of the `span`

```
var span = $('#your_span_id')[0],
    sel, range;

if(window.getSelection){
    sel = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();

    range.selectNode(span);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
 } else {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(span);
    range.select()
 }
```

fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpJDa/)

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining what the code does.